# my nav element are not showing different screen after clinking the nav links

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, navbar

```
**html code**   
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1 id="root"></h1>
      
    </body>
    </html>
**JavaScript code**
    import React from "react";
    import Nav from "./Navbar/Nav";
    import Company from "./Navbar/Screens/Company";
    import Home from "./Navbar/Screens/Home";
    import About from "./Navbar/Screens/About";
    import Gallary from "./Navbar/Screens/Gallary";
    import Contect from "./Navbar/Screens/Contact";
    import Others from "./Navbar/Screens/Others";
    
    export default function App(){
```

- //even after doing it again same thing is happening this is most
  likely error from my part

  ```
       let component 
       switch (window.location.pathname) {
           case "/Company":
               component:<Company />
               break;  
           case "/Home":
                   component:<Home />
                   break;
           case "/About":
               component:<About />
               break;
           case "/Contect":
               component:<Contect />
               break;
           case "/Gallary":
               component:<Gallary />
               break;
           case "/Others":
               component:<Others />
               break;
           default:
               component:<Company/>
               break;
       }


       return(
           <div>
               <>
                   <Nav /> 
                   {component}
               </>
           </div>
       )
   }
  ```

  **using pathname  i am opening the different js (which ruens some code) it show that the pathway is open but not rendering the code on the webpage which is just a h1**

Comment: You are not actually setting `component` to anything, also please use https://reactrouter.com/en/main

Comment: do I have to ? I am just using simple Js created right there and using it right there can you please elaborate

Comment: You cannot use classical navigation like `<a href="/about">` with react since it's a one-page app. You can simulate it though, which is why react router was created in the first place: to make that process much easier to set up. If you want to solve this without react-router, you need to show at the very least your Nav component.

Comment: it works thanks and i used colon instead of equal to sign and learned little about router